# Penalized Log-Likelihood - Logistic regression

Tags: logistic, nonparametric, regularization

Equation 5.30 of [*The Elements of Statistical Learning*](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) states that the penalized log-likelihood for a nonparametric logistic regression is:

\begin{align}
l(f;\lambda) &= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\big[y_i\log p(x_i) +(1-y_i)\log(1-p(x_i))\big] - \frac12\lambda \int{f''(t)}^2dt  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\big[y_if(x_i) - \log(1+e^{f(x_i)}\big] - \frac12\lambda \int{f''(t)}^2dt  
\end{align}

I've read through [Negative binomial log-likelihood in penalized regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174093/negative-binomial-log-likelihood-in-penalized-regression) and [What is penalized logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216187/what-is-penalized-logistic-regression) but I haven't come across this formulation yet.

I'm familiar with LASSO and ridge, but the penalized parameter is a vector of $\beta$ coefficients. In this non-parametric scheme, can someone explain why we penalize $\int{f''(t)}^2dt$ instead? I understand that for the non-parametric case, $f(x)$ acts similar to $\beta$ in the parametric case. But it's not obvious to me why this is how it's formulated. Note that

$$f(x) = \log\frac{P(Y = 1|X=x)}{P(Y=0|X=x)}$$

Comment: penalised just means adding a penalty term (which is pretty broad). But  the link you refer to refers back to section 5.4 smoothing splines - adding a penalty to enforce smoothness

Comment: Right, I understand that it's a penalty term. But why that specific form (integral of square of second derivative)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline

Comment: Of course Wikipedia! So, like most things, this penalty is chosen for convenience/out of tradition. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @seanv507's link to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline):

This formulation is based on the class of twice differentiable functions, and

> The roughness penalty based on the second derivative is the most
>   common in modern statistics literature, although the method can easily
>   be adapted to penalties based on other derivatives.

This answers my question.